# What ip is attached to php curl request?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, php-curl

Im trying to send a curl request from a website and the receiving endpoint need my website ip address to give me access to the endpoint.

My curl request is saying unauthorized because my website ip has not been white listed and i use wordpress ajax to send info to the pho curl.

My question is, which ip is being attached to the curl request. Is it the user ip or the website ip?

The website im sending from is a dub domain in this format "myweb.mydomain.com" and i submitted the share ip of mydomain.com because they use the same ip.
Please i need help to know if the endpoint providers are the ones that didn't add my website ip to white list, or the problem is from me.

Ive tried to know if the share ip is the ip of all my subdomains and main website and also contacted the endpoint providers which they said my ip has been white listed.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  Which IP was whitelisted?  Do you happen to have the public ip of whatever system's that sending the curl instructions?   Is it the same one that the endpoint providers has whitelisted?

Comment: Im the one sending so,  i provided the endpoint providers with mu share ip address of my website to white list which they said they did. But whenever i make a curl request it says unauthorized, meaning my ip has not been white listed. What i want to know is if i use wordpress ajax to submit a form and send the curl request, will the curl request be sent from my website ip of the user's ip?

Comment: From the website’s server ip.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Lets say you are the the endpoint provider. To use your endpoint i will provide you with my website ip else my request will return unauthorized. After providing you with my ip and you give me access, i made a request to your endpoint and it returns unauthorized. What could be the problem?

Comment: Im using ajax to take user input to submit to my php code. Could my website user's ip address be attached to my curl request or it will maintain my website's ip?